# android studio graphic editor no showing the layout picture

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason on the project I am working on in Android Studio the XML graphic editor has stopped showing me the picture of the screen layout. The app itself works fine and the layout woks fine on my device, but I don't have a picture of it on my computer screen in the editor.

The editor shows a error **Rendering Problem - Exception raised during rendering**
in the details it shows me a stack trace of a **java.lang.NullPointerException**, and it tip is to try and refresh the layout, but that doesn't work. I tried to refresh, to rebuild, and every other kind of refresh possible but nothing works. I checked other projects that I had worked on and thy where OK the graphics  was fine, but not on my current project. So I need help finding the problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptFont(BidiRenderer.java:290)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptRuns(BidiRenderer.java:280)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:133)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:108)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.measureText(Paint_Delegate.java:1310)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetTextAdvances(Paint_Delegate.java:972)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetRunAdvance(Paint_Delegate.java:1147)
at android.graphics.Paint.nGetRunAdvance(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2729)
at android.text.TextLine.getRunAdvance(TextLine.java:729)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:778)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1018)
at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:417)
at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:310)
at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:281)
at android.text.Layout.measurePara(Layout.java:1966)
at android.text.Layout.getDesiredWidthWithLimit(Layout.java:186)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8168)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
at android.widget.Toolbar.measureChildCollapseMargins(Toolbar.java:1548)
at android.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure(Toolbar.java:1662)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6622)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onMeasure(ActionBarContainer.java:291)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6622)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:378)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:590)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:343)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Here is the full stack trace:

Comment: where is your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

In xml toolbar you can find refresh button, so that it will notify if it is any warnings in your xml.
If your used custom layout then rendering problem shown..

Comment: I did a refresh it didn't help. And I have done custom layout before with no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let see the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptFont(BidiRenderer.java:290)
```

I think you need to clone project like library module, then add @Nullable  to this method to avoid exception here.

Comment: You want me to edit the source code of Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

if view is rendering fine at run time but you are only having problem showing preview in layout editor then you should use **isInEditMode()** method and should not do unsupported operations if view is being rendered in layout editor

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
       if (!isInEditMode()) {
           //custom logic
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that your answers did not help me at all. The solution for me was to go back to one of my backup visions, when the edit display still worked, and start from there. I found that when changing too many parameters in the Theme Editor (three) cause a bug that stops the XML editor from showing the layout picture.

One of the things I learned many years ago when first started to learn programming was that there is no such thing as to many backups, this is one of those time when I am glad I listed to my teachers.